# Adjusting the radius of a rectangle by dragging a corner handle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, trigonometry

I am building a design tool and am stuck understanding how to build this functionality. I have a good chunk of it done here https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-mendeleev-dsgvx?file=/src/App.tsx but it's a bit wonky.

The feature I am trying to recreate can be found in Figma or Sketch, here is a recording https://share.getcloudapp.com/yAuDed8k

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { RadiusControlWrap, RadiusControlStyle, CornerKnob } from "./Styles";

interface IRadiusControlProps {
  size: any;
  radius: number;
  onRadiusChange: (radius: number) => void;
}

const RadiusControl: FC<IRadiusControlProps> = ({
  size,
  radius,
  onRadiusChange
}) => {
  const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState<any>(false);

  const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
    (e: any) => {
      if (mouseDown && e.target && e.target.parentElement) {
        const rect = e.target.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = Math.round(Number(e.clientX - rect.left));
        const y = Math.round(Number(e.clientY - rect.top));
        const val = Math.round(Math.atan2(y, x) * 100);

        // TODO: Understand how to set the correct value
        onRadiusChange(val);
      }
    },
    [mouseDown, onRadiusChange]
  );

  const handleMouseUp = (e: any) => {
    setMouseDown(false);
  };

  const handleMouseDown = (e: any) => {
    setMouseDown(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mouseDown) {
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [handleMouseMove, mouseDown]);

  // TODO: how to scale the knobs like Figma or Sketch
  return (
    <RadiusControlWrap>
      <RadiusControlStyle
        style={{
          width: size.width - 30 - radius,
          height: size.height - 30 - radius
        }}
      >
        <CornerKnob corner="tl" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} />
        <CornerKnob corner="bl" />
        <CornerKnob corner="tr" />
        <CornerKnob corner="br" />
      </RadiusControlStyle>
    </RadiusControlWrap>
  );
};

export default RadiusControl;
```

The math I am struggling with the most is inside `handleMouseMove`. I am using the arctan of the y & x coordinates, rounding, and multiplying by 100 -- clearly wrong.

As you can see in the Figma screen share, the math there is perfectly proportional to the center of the object, the radius seems to be calculated from the arctan difference between the edge and the center, setting the roundedness accordingly.

Also, the handles appear to be in a rectangle form and get scaled-down proportionally until they meet in the middle -- or in the matter of a rectangle when they meet on the x-axis.

Hoping this makes sense and someone with some JS and Trigonometry experience can help.

You can find all the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-mendeleev-dsgvx?file=/src/RadiusControl.tsx:0-1987 in case you missed it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line...

```
const val = Math.round(Math.atan2(y, x) * 100);
```

...to...

```
const val = Math.sqrt( x * x + y * y );
```

In short, the original code is obtaining the angle (in radians) of the cursor to the corner, so after grabbing the control point, if you move the cursor generally left or right you will see a smooth corner transition as you're smoothly transitioning the angle of the cursor relative to the corner.

The suggested code simply measures the distance of the cursor to the corner.

That being said, this doesn't solve the entire problem.  When the `handleMouseDown` event occurs, there's a need to trap the current cursor location AND the current distance to the rectangle corner AND the current rectangle corner radius.  This will then allow you to calculate the change in the distance to the corner from the original cursor location, and subsequently the change in the rectangle radius...